# Test Build Matrix Expansion of Travis

Tags: travis-ci

I have a valid `.travis.yml` locally in my repository. Let's take the example from the travis help: https://github.com/travis-ci/build-stages-demo/blob/matrix-expansion/.travis.yml

How can I see the resulting build matrix that travis would create, i.e. an overview of all jobs with all stages [like this](https://travis-ci.org/travis-ci/build-stages-demo/builds/230344299),  without having to commit and push my repository?

PS: I only need the result of the Build Matrix, I don't need the jobs to actually run.

Answer (score 3):

Travis at the time of writing does not have such feature.

But matrix logic is quite simple (main part in travis_api in [travis/model/build/config/matrix.rb](https://github.com/travis-ci/travis-api/blob/72fac430b2615e6f5ff7e3371f74bfa621ef59df/lib/travis/model/build/config/matrix.rb#L15)) - it:

1. creates all combinations of top level parameters that are arrays (rvm/env/etc.)
2. removes combinations that match any `matrix/exclude` pattern
3. adds included combinations (have hot found duplicate handling, probably they are removed somewhere later)

If you really want to see what travis expands your config into - there's no other way that run it (third party tools cannot guarantee their results to be accurate event if they copy code from travis - it may change in the future). To make it faster - you can substitute your actual tests with a stub like `script: 'true'`